# Using Context with an Object of Arrays using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on using context in react applications.  I am not sure how to describe what follows, but I am thinking maybe it is an object of arrays.  My question is how I extract the title which contains the word, 'hat'.  This is just one item.  Otherwise, it would contain more of these items that I would also extract.  What I tried is:  categoriesMap[0] and the like.  Nothing worked.  Thanks, Joshua.

```js
categoriesMap[category] = 
    
  [
    {
        title: 'hats',
        items: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Brown Brim',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/ZYW3VTp/brown-brim.png',
                price: 25,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Blue Beanie',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/ypkgK0X/blue-beanie.png',
                price: 18,
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Brown Cowboy',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/QdJwgmp/brown-cowboy.png',
                price: 35,
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Grey Brim',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/RjBLWxB/grey-brim.png',
                price: 25,
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                name: 'Green Beanie',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/YTjW3vF/green-beanie.png',
                price: 18,
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                name: 'Palm Tree Cap',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/rKBDvJX/palm-tree-cap.png',
                price: 14,
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                name: 'Red Beanie',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/bLB646Z/red-beanie.png',
                price: 18,
            },
            {
                id: 8,
                name: 'Wolf Cap',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/1f2nWMM/wolf-cap.png',
                price: 14,
            },
            {
                id: 9,
                name: 'Blue Snapback',
                imageUrl: 'https://i.ibb.co/X2VJP2W/blue-snapback.png',
                price: 16,
            },
        ],
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the title that contains the word 'hat' from the categoriesMap, you can use the filter and find array methods. Here's an example of how you can achieve that:

```
const searchTerm = 'hat';

// Filter the categories to find the one that contains the word 'hat'
const categoryWithHat = categoriesMap.find(category => category.title.includes(searchTerm));

if (categoryWithHat) {
  const title = categoryWithHat.title;
  console.log(title); // Output: 'hats'

  // Access the items within the category
  const items = categoryWithHat.items;
  console.log(items); // Output: Array of items
} else {
  console.log('No category found with the word "hat"');
}
```

In this code, the find method is used to filter the categoriesMap array and find the category that has the title containing the word 'hat'. If a matching category is found, its title and items can be accessed. Otherwise, if no matching category is found, an appropriate message can be displayed.

Remember to replace categoriesMap with the actual variable name you're using in your code.

Comment: Thanks for such a complete solution.  Sincerely, Joshua.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I can't get the find to work, I get:  categoriesMap.find is not a function.
Perhaps because it is not a simple array?  Would you continue to help me, please?  Here is the code:

```js
const Category = ({}) => {

   // log.console("cat", {category});
   
  let { category } = useParams();
  
    //console.log("ca: ",category);  
  //category = "hats";
  const { categoriesMap } = useContext(CategoriesContext);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(categoriesMap[category]);
   
  console.log("category :", categoriesMap.title);


    const searchTerm = "hats";
    const categoriesMapWithHat = categoriesMap.find(category => category.title.includes(searchTerm));
    const title = categoriesMapWithHat.title;
    alert("title: ", title);
```

Comment: Please post actual sample data for `categoriesMap` (with expected output).

Comment: The sample data is above and the expected output is, "hats".

Comment: That is not full sample data. It does not show how `categoriesMap` is initialized and we have to guess what `category` is.

Comment: Unmitigated, thanks for helping me with my thoughts.  My answer is seemingly to use a prop or context for the index of the array.  We'll see if this is right!